# Dropdown that automatically copies the selected first dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have two dropdowns, My question is what javascript function that the 2nd dropdown will automatically select that the 1st dropdown selected?

Here's my code

```html
<select  name="b"  maxlength=2 style="width:70px; height:30px;" autocomplete="off" required/>
 <option>NMG</option>
  <option>PRI</option>
 <option>FMNIC</option>
 </select>

<select  name="b"  maxlength=2 style="width:70px; height:30px;" autocomplete="off" required/>
 <option>NMG</option>
  <option>PRI</option>
 <option>FMNIC</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use onchange,

```
<select  name="b"  maxlength=2 style="width:70px; height:30px;" autocomplete="off" required onChange="setData(this);"/>
<option>NMG</option>
<option>PRI</option>
<option>FMNIC</option>
</select>

<select  name="b" Id="second"  maxlength=2 style="width:70px; height:30px;" autocomplete="off" required/>
<option>NMG</option>
<option>PRI</option>
<option>FMNIC</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**:

```
function setData(ctl)
{
   document.getElementById("second").value = ctl.value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery makes this pretty simple...

```
$(function() {
    // Bind the onchange event of the 1st select.
    $('select').eq(0).change(SelectionChanged);
});

function SelectionChanged() {
    var selectedValue = $('select').eq(0).val();
    $('select').eq(1).val( selectedValue  );
}
```